# Disable 3G wireless access on a Kindle Paperwhite

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, power-management, 3g

Is there a way to disable the 3G cellular access to preserve the battery while keeping the wifi access?

Airplane mode kills both the cellular and the wifi.